# How to enable Brotli on Debian 10 with DirectAdmin?

Tags: apache, debian, directadmin, brotli

I'm running the latest version of DA (1.61.3), PHP 7.4.7 en Apache 2.4.43 on a Debian 10 server. I want to add Brotli support en did this:

- Installed Brotli package on Debian (apt-get install brotli)
- Added brotli module to apache for custombuild, following: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=191 (--with-brotli)

After this I checked at https://www.brotli.pro and https://tools.keycdn.com/brotli-test, but it fails, says: no Brotli support.

In PHP info I see under the section curl this:

[image: phpinfo]

Before BROTLI was not mentoined here, so something is installed, but as you can see the value is "No".

What do I have to do more to enable Brotli?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
Check if the brotli module is really active in Apache:

httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES

then recompile the php

cd  /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build php
./build rewrite_confs